# Parsing String Variable in Bash Script

Tags: string, bash, shell, parsing, delimiter

I am working on a bash script that will parse a full string name to provide me with a firmware value. 
For example the original string name will be something like:

```
Example_v0p1
```

Desired Output:

```
0.1
```

The first part of my function deliminates the string based on the underscore value and sets the second element of the array equal to a variable called version:

```
arr=(`echo $1| tr '_' ' '`)
version=${arr[1]}
```

Using the example I provided, $version now equals "v0p1". I am searching for a way to parse this string further so that it will look like the desired output.

If it is possible I would like the solution to be able to handle multiple variations of the same format so that I can use the same script for all of the version codes that could be generated. The syntax however will always be the same. v#p#{p#p#....} 
Examples:

```
v0p1p1
v3p2p0p1
v1p3
```

Desired output:

```
0.1.1 
3.2.0.1
1.3
```

I am unsure of the best way to approach this problem. I am not experienced enough with REGEX's to accomplish this and I cannot come up with an appropriate way to parse the strings because they are going to be different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
s='v3p2p0p1'
ver=$(sed 's/p/./g' <<< "${s:1}")

echo "$ver"
3.2.0.1

s='v0p1p1'
ver=$(sed 's/p/./g' <<< "${s:1}")

echo "$ver"
0.1.1
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind can you explain the piece  that says `<<< "${s:1}" `

Comment: `<<<` is called here-string to feed in some value to `sed` command.

Comment: Instead of echo, I need the output to be stored into a variable

Comment: Check updated answer for storing derived version in a variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. That is exactly what I needed. MUCH nicer than my original approach.

Answer (score 3):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
for v in v0p1p1 v3p2p0p1 v1p3 ; do
    v=${v//[vp]/.}             # Replace v's and p's with dots.
    v=${v#.}                   # Remove the leading dot.
    echo "$v"
done
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you with the explanation. What you have declared as "v" is actually three separate strings. I was just unsure how to show that in the block

Comment: @StephenWeaver: For a single string, you can skip the second replacement. I updated the answer.

Comment: This worked nicely as well, thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @StephenWeaver, I'd suggest this answer as the accepted one -- if you put it inside a tight loop, you'll observe that its performance is far, _far_ better than shelling out to `sed`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I appreciate the time it took for choroba to help me; however, I did not choose this as the best answer because I do not need the loop. anubhava provided me with exactly what I wanted. A simple solution that applies to every instance. I only require the script to handle a single variable. His answer is more acceptable for the problem he presented, it just simply was not my particular problem.

Comment: @StephenWeaver, I disagree that anything about this is specific to the loop -- I mentioned a loop only because that's where performance issues in bash are most typically magnified to a point of being user-noticeable. Take the contents out of the loop, and you still have a far higher-performance approach.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var="$(echo "v0p1p1" | tr -s 'vp' " .")"
```

It replaces `v` with space though.

If you don't want that you can do:

```
var=$(echo "v0p1p1" | tr -d 'v' | tr -s 'p' '.')
```